# Returning Code from a TypeScript Module in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a simple page which two main parts: `Menu` and `Guide`. In my `App,tsx`, I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import Guide from './Guide/Guide';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Guide />
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is fine.

But, in the `./Guide/Guide.tsx`, I have:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from "./Menu/Menu";

export default class Guide extends Component {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
    }

    return (
        <Menu />
    );
}
```

`Menu.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Menu extends Component {
    return (
        <h1>Test</h1>
    );
};
```

However I'm getting the error `'return', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.`.

What's going on here?

You can probably tell I'm very new to React and TypeScript!

Comment: you are missing render method on class component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class component (such as your Guide and Menu components), you render some HTML code inside the `render` function. Insinde functional components (such as your App component), you render some HTML code inside the `return` function. Here you are mixing those 2 different syntax, that is why you are getting this error.

In order to fix this, simply replace your `return` function in the Menu and Guide components by the `render` function